# My if statement statment before my else if and else statement is not running. Why is javascript by passing this statement

Tags: javascript

this is a snippet of some code i am working on for the pass few days. i need to know why my if statement is being bypassed by the console. its supposed to give me an alert if a box is not checked. it instead bypasses the argument and runs my else if and the following else statement.

#### question one

```
            <input type="checkbox" class="question" value="Bike" id="qOne" value="ans1"> answer one
            <input type="checkbox" class="question" value="Car"  id="qTwo" value="ans2"> answer two<br>
            <input type="checkbox" class="question" value="Car"  id="qThree" value="ans3"> answer three
            <input type="checkbox" class="question" value="Car"  id="qFour" value="ans4"> answer four<br>




<button type="submit" value="Submit" id="testSubmit" onclick="ansSubmit()"> Submit</button>
</form>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function ansSubmit(){
    var ans = document.getElementById('qThree');
    var ansCheck = ans.checked; 
    var check = document.getElementsByClassName('question').checked;

    if(check = false){
        alert('Please select an answer');//if check is not checked then alert a warning
    }else if(ansCheck !== true ){
        document.getElementById('testSubmit').style.backgroundColor = "red";//if ans not checked then turn button red
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('testSubmit').style.backgroundColor = "green";//turn button green
    }
}
```

Comment: The comparison operator is not `=` but `==`...

Comment: If your code have a weird behaviour you should run it through http://jshint.com/ (or similar) it'll tell you if something is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

`=` is the assignment operator. To compare for equality, use `==` or `===`.

Answer (score 1):

`=` takes the value on its right hand side and assigns it to the variable on its left hand side. It also returns the value that was assigned, so your first conditional check essentially evaluates to `if (false)`.

`==` compares for equality but doesn't enforce types to be the same, while `===` does.

```js
console.log(false == 0) // true
console.log(false === 0) // false
```

So, you should replace `if(check = false){` in your code with `if (!check) {` which is essentially `if (check == false) {`.

You can read more about JavaScript comparison operators here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a value (false) to the variable check inside your if statement's condition by using only the = operator.  Thats why it will never pass inside the if block.

The correct way should be:

```
if(check === false){
        alert('Please select an answer');//if check is not checked then alert a warning
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of check = false try check  == false.  I'm guessing it doesn't see this expression as boolean and that's the root of the problem.

Comment: The `=` operator returns the value that was assigned, i.e. `foo = false` evaluates to `false` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lines in if(check = false), you are using an assignment operator instead a comparison one, furthermore, I'd avoid using comparison to boolean values like that, may I suggest:

```
if(!check){
    alert('Please select an answer');//if check is not checked then alert a warning
}else if(!ansCheck){
    document.getElementById('testSubmit').style.backgroundColor = "red";//if ans not checked then turn button red
}
else{
    document.getElementById('testSubmit').style.backgroundColor = "green";//turn button green
```